# What kind of ODE is this?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Trying to find a solution to this using something like Schaum's but I cannot find anything near to its form

$$
\ddot{y}(t)+\alpha e^{-i 2 \omega t} y(t) = 0
$$

Answer (score 0):

Enforcing the substitution $x=\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\omega}e^{-i\omega t}$ in the ODE given by

$$\frac{d^2 y(t)}{dt^2}+\alpha e^{-i2\omega t}y(t)=0$$

yields the new ODE with $f(x)=y(t(x))$

$$x^2f''(x)+xf'(x)-x^2 y(x)=0\tag 2$$

The ODE in $(2)$ is the ODE for the [Modified Bessel Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I.CE.B1.2C_K.CE.B1) of order $0$.  The general solution to $(2)$ is therefore given by

$$f(x)=AI_0(x)+BK_0(x) \tag 3$$

whereupon setting $x=\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\omega}e^{-i\omega t}$ in $(3)$ yields

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{y(t)=AI_0\left(\frac{\sqrt a}{\omega}e^{-i\omega t}\right)+BK_0\left(\frac{\sqrt a}{\omega}e^{-i\omega t}\right)}$$